# Calling Spring component from groovy

Tags: java, spring, groovy, autowired

I have a spring-based java application with some useful components. As a part of the system I have a groovy script, to process some reports. I would like to call a spring component from groovy script. 
When I'm writing in Java, I need to use `@Autowired` annotation inside the `@Component`, i.e.

```
@Component
class Reporter{
@Autowired
SearchService searchService;

void report(){
 searchService.search(...);
 ...
}
}
```

How can I do the same from groovy?
At first, how I can define `@Component` for whole script?
The following code:

```
@Component class Holder{
    @Autowired
    SearchService searchService;

    def run(){
        searchService.search("test");
    }
}

new Holder().run()
```

fails with NPE on `searchService`.
I'm running groovyscripts with `GroovyClassloader` instatiaded from Java, if it matters.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How is the spring application context created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `@Component`, you should create Spring context as:

```
def ctx = new GenericApplicationContext()
new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(ctx).scan('') // scan root package for components
ctx.refresh()
```

or in the XML:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>
```

Your code should work if the context is created as above. Here is an example from [Groovy Codehaus](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Spring+Factories+with+Groovy)

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component class CalcImpl3 {
    @Autowired private AdderImpl adder
    def doAdd(x, y) { adder.add(x, y) }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it's exactly what I needed. Btw I noticed, that it takes some time to create and refresh context. Probably it would be better to pass spring context as a parameter to groovy script, wouldn't it?

Comment: you can definitely try that, but the context still needs to be refreshed ( e.g. for `@Autowired` to work + other things )

Comment: Thanks for this answer, most usefull on the web at the moment :D however, after annotating my Groovy class with Component and inserting the 3 lines about context in my constructor, I still cannot Autowire a Service that I have in my Spring project. It's telling me that it seems to miss configuration (liquibase config) but I have my application.yml file nice and lean :(

Answer (score 1):

Three possibilities:

1. If your Groovy code can be pre-compiled and included in the classpath then it will be created and injected as any other bean would be during `<context:component-scan>`.   It sounds like this may not be the case since you are using `GroovyClassLoader`.
2. Use Spring [Dynamic Language Support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/dynamic-language.html#dynamic-language-beans-groovy) and use `<lang:groovy>` to create your bean instead of using `GroovyClassLoader`.   Then use `<lang:property>` to inject your properties instead of using `@Autowired`.
3. If you still need to use `GroovyClassLoader` then you can ask the bean to be injected by using `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.

For example, if `obj` is a reference to the object created by `GroovyClassLoader`:

```
AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor aabpp =
    (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor)applicationContext.
        getBean(AnnotationConfigUtils.AUTOWIRED_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME);

aabpp.processInjection(obj);
```

There is a fourth possibility too, but I am not sure if it works with `GroovyClassLoader`, that is to use [Load-time Weaving](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.  As far as I understand, your answer is useful when we need to implement a bean in groovy, right? For now, I just want to call existing component from the groovy script, so it's not useful for me right now. But I'll save your answer for later reference.